# Why doesn't p6spy show the correct spatial query for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial, p6spy

I set p6spy to show all SQL statements. But it doesn't show correct SQLstatements for spatial a query. Here is one example:

```
select * 
  from ( select this_.myactivity_id as y0_ 
           from mytable this_ 
          where this_.start_time_local >= '2012-01-08 17:02:59.575' 
            and sdo_within_distance( this_.start_point
                             , 'oracle.sql.STRUCT@3848d632'
                             , 'DISTANCE=8845.042641272024 UNIT=meter ') = 'TRUE'
          order by this_.start_time_gmt desc ) 
 where rownum <= 10
```

The spatial object is represented as 'oracle.sql.STRUCT@3848d632'. Do you know how to make it show correctly?

Thanks,